# recursion leads to never ending error when it does not pass if statement

Tags: python, boolean

I don't know if this is entirely recusion related but i added a small function within my main function to block non-integer inputs with

```
def main(depth, size):
    depth = eval(input("Enter depth that is an integer: "))
    if (isinstance( depth, int)) == False:
        print( 'Not an integer' )
        main(depth, size)
    else:
        pass
    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.speed(100)
    triangle(depth, size)

def triangle(depth, size):
    if depth == 0:
        pass
    else:
        turtle.forward(size)
        triangle(depth-1, size/2)
        turtle.right(120)
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.left(120)
        triangle(depth-1, size/2)
        turtle.right(120)
        turtle.right(120)
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(120)

main(depth, 100)
```

when I input an integer the program runs fine, when I input a non-int, it returns and tells me it's not an integer and returns to the input stage. then when i put in an integer, it starts drawing the picture as it should, then goes a little bit further, gets hung up at a recurson on line 27 with "triangle(depth-1, size/2)".

I'm so close to finishing this program, I just need to make it harder to crash.

Comment: Don't use `eval()` to change a string to an integer. Use `int()`

Comment: but if the user inputs say, "3.3" it brings in an error. the goal is to avoid that error.

Comment: That causes it to always be a float. How could I check if it is an integer and stop the program if it's not? That's why I use eval() because it allows me to check if something is an integer.

Comment: From a style point of view, you should prefer `if not isinstance(depth, int):` over `if (isinstance( depth, int)) == False:`

Comment: The simplest fixed is to return right after you recourse into `main`. It is broken because you let it proceed after that, but depth is not an int. That doesn't make it good style though, as the answer days you should use a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User input is not a good candidate for (non-tail) recursion, since the depth is unbounded. Just do it iteratively:

```
def main(size):
    while True:
        depth = input("Enter depth that is an integer: ")
        try:
            depth = int(depth)
        except ValueError:
            print('Not an integer')
        else:
            break

    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.speed(100)
    triangle(depth, size)
```

Comment: Thank you this actually answers the problem at hand. I only know the basic logic operators.

Comment: Note that `try ... except ... else ... finally` is a statement, not an operator